# Running php script from comand line

Tags: php, cmd

SO I'm trying to get a php script file to run from command line. This is a test of the command as when I have it working i should be able to make a scheduled task using that command to run the script every five minutes. Oddly enough when running it from the command line I get an error but if I were to navigate to the php file through my browser it works for its intended purpose.

Here's the command I'm running:

```
Z:\>php -f "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\IT Helpdesk\inc\mail\hesk_pop3.php"
```

And here's the output:

```
´╗┐The temporary directory "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\IT Helpdesk/attachments/44b767c4d
f322d255695e8ef356f4d0f" doesn't exist.
```

I can't work out why it would run on the browser fine but not in the command line. Is it my command? If I run it again I get a different message:

```
´╗┐The temporary directory "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\IT Helpdesk/attachments/26ff3c6dd
b0e3c84e0b36bd5543ad270" doesn't exist.
```

The php script seems to be trying to create a temporary directory which makes me think that it could be a permission issue with the file. Does the command prompt run under my user account or a system account?

Any help on where I might be going wrong would be much appreciated

EDIT

Seems I was on the right track thinking about permissions. I gave user accounts modification control over the file (oddly I didn't have it despite being admin). This meant that the script could run through the command line which is exactly what I need.

Thanks for putting up with my ramblings. Sometimes trying to explain your problem helps to understand it!

Comment: It is likely a permissions issue as the command prompt does run as your user. To verify, you could try running the script in an 'Elevated Command Prompt' ... right-click on Command Prompt in the start menu and click 'Run As Administrator' (provided you're on a newer version of Windows/Windows Server)

Comment: yeah just as I posted it I change the file permissions and its working now. Just had to make sure that user / admin accounts had the ability to modify the file too.